# Why aren’t sunsets red when viewed from low earth orbit?

Tags: visible-light, scattering, atmospheric-science, sun

So “Why are sunsets red?” seems to be a pretty common question and it has to do with Rayleigh scattering in the atmosphere. I’m following some [game dev tutorials](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter16.html) ([example implementation](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/lslXDr)) on how to model and simulate this effect in computer graphics with the relevant scattering equations.

Every model has a strong red tinge near the terminator, especially when viewed from the night side of the earth, looking towards the sun, much like how sunsets look from the ground.

[image]
[image]

Yet, when I look at various NASA images from the ISS, the red color is barely visible at all!

[image]
[image]
[image]

[This](https://c1.staticflickr.com/8/7161/6731872025_0a1f116fed_b.jpg) is the only image I could find that contains even a trace of red coloring.

All atmospheric scattering implementations I have seen use the line integrals from the nvidia [article](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter16.html) linked earlier. What are they missing?

Comment: In my region a strong "pink" sunset  is not so probable, as it is mostly dry (Greece). The third and fourth pictures above would represent the "pinkness" we get maybe 5% of the time. Maybe the models use an average humidity which will give lots of red? whereas the humidity is variable and transient?

Answer (score 3):

In ISS, the red phase of sunset, that is the descent of the Sun through the troposphere, lasts only a few seconds. In contrast, the blue crescent of the upper atmosphere is visible for several minutes. Therefore the red phase is missing on many sunset photos from ISS.

[image: Sunrise at ISS]
Sunrise at ISS. Source: [NASA/Scott Kelly](https://www.flickr.com/photos/nasa2explore/20515597136/)

Similar [photo](https://apod.nasa.gov/apod/ap100623.html) and [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HVDHvcrwVRs#t=3m0s)

Comment: If you look at the [example implementation](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/lslXDr) given in the OP, you'll see that when the simulated Sun is behind the Earth, the red ring is always present. So in the model used this phase lasts not a few seconds — the whole night. Thus this answer appears wrong: it's not the bad timing which makes the model diverge from reality, it must be something else.

Answer (score 1):

There's some interesting info in a more recent paper on this topic: [E. Bruneton and F. Neyret, *Precomputed Atmospheric Scattering*](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00288758/en). This paper, among other things, cites O'Neil's paper and discusses some of its (and other papers') shortcomings.

Also, although this new paper is an improvement as compared to O'Neil's paper, it still has its limitations, which the authors did note:

> **Limitations** A limitation of our method is that the aerosol
>   properties are assumed constant, depending only on altitude,
>   whereas in fact they can greatly change depending on the
>   atmospheric conditions [Slo02]. Since our precomputations
>   are very fast we can change these properties quickly, but they
>   remain uniform.

This *might* be one of the reasons, i.e. that they take aerosols to have some particular altitude distribution everywhere, while it may vary much. If aerosol density is exaggerated, you'll get the too high reddish component.

One of the good things about this paper is that its demo is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/ebruneton/precomputed_atmospheric_scattering), so you can download it and play with parameters (including source codes). [Online demo](https://ebruneton.github.io/precomputed_atmospheric_scattering/demo.html) is now also available.

Answer (score -1):

The red sunset is due to Mie scattering. Gustav Mie, a not so well known physicist who had early ideas similar to gauge theory, worked on light scattering by micron-sized particles. The physics is rather complicated for classical EM. The result is that the intensity of scattered radiation of wavelength $\lambda$ by spherical particles of radius $r$ a distance $d$ from the observer is
$$
I~=~\frac{I_0}{2d^2}\frac{d^6}{\lambda^4 r^6}(1~+~cos^2\theta).
$$
This has a curious consequence, in that for $\theta$ small the scatter is large, but also the case happens for $\theta$ near $\pi$ or $180^o$. The next time you see a great sunset look east and you might find there is a red sky there too. This is the Mie backscatter.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The question was "what the models used are missing" (i.e. why their results fail to match observations), not where the red color comes from in general.